# Want use animation when display data

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

How to display data that i retrieved from database using animation like waterfall effect or rolling effect?have no idea how to do it,please give some idea/reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**vague question.Some hints:**

1)

```
<div style="text-shadow: 6px/*X-Offset*/ -9px/*Y-Offset*/ 1px/*Blur Radius*/ white/*Shadow Color*/, 6px/*X-Offset*/ 9px/*Y-Offset*/ 5px/*Blur Radius*/ red/*Shadow Color*/; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Text Shadow</div>
```

2)

```
<div style="margin-left:30px; color: #fff;
    text-shadow:
    0px -1px 0px white,
    0px -2px 0px yellow,
    0px -10px 0px #ff8000,
    0px -18px 0px red;font-size:80px">
On Fire, pretty hot</div>
```

3)

```
<div id="exTransition2" class="shadow">
<img class="top" src="images/color.jpg" />
<img class="bottom" src="images/BlackNwhite.jpg" />
</div>

#exTransition2 {
  position:relative;
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#exTransition2 img 
{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  max-width:100%; max-height:100%
}

#exTransition2 img.top:hover 
{
  opacity:0;
}
```

**Note**-Instead of prefefined text in above example,you can give your own text retreived from databse(backend)

**Tutorial**-http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-text-effects/